# Did this sentence use two preposition 'over, by' together?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, redundancy

> He assumed that I was waiting for winners **over by** the squirt guns,
>   and then slipping a fifty to some guy who didn't realize how a giant stuffed animal could change the world's perception of him - [*source*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vW9A4dXdwUAC&pg=PT85&lpg=PT85&dq=%22assumed%20that%20I%20was%20waiting%20for%20winners%22&source=bl&ots=peyrW44tpZ&sig=AvpuKmfYEfdcKrEuWjlA3USmQG0&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22assumed%20that%20I%20was%20waiting%20for%20winners%22&f=false)

I guessed that someone was waiting for winners who had won the squirt guns game using squirt guns. but it is odd in my opinion. So,i don't know why,how 'by' did be used in sentence.

Comment: Yes, the writer used two prepositions together. *Over* is not an adverb here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Over by" is a construction that means "**over there, next to**".

**Over**, among its many meanings, is an adverb meaning ["across a space or distance"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over).

**By**, in this case, means ["in proximity to", or "near to"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by) (not "through the agency or instrumentality of", in this case) - see the very first definition at the link.

So the speaker is saying that the other person assumed he would be waiting *at some distance, next to* the squirt guns.

Comment: @inches: http://www.lightstalking.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Peasants_in_an_Interior_1661_Adriaen_van_Ostade.jpg   The man sitting at a table in the background, smoking his pipe, could say to a person sitting next to him, "The little girl and her dog are *over by* the fireplace."