# "Over near" meaning

Tags: adverbs, redundancy

What is the meaning of "over near" expression in these sentence? What kind of grammatical structure is?

> There are three courts **over near** the football field and four behind the pro shop.

Comment: "Over" is an adverb that means "[across a space or distance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over)".  Please refer to "[Did this sentence use two preposition 'over, by' together?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73594/did-this-sentence-use-two-preposition-over-by-together)" to see if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be confused by the fact that "over" and "near" are side by side.

**over** can mean "at a place a distance away from us"

> The dog is *over* near the tree.

The dog is at a place which is a distance from us, near the tree.

A synonym for this meaning of "over" is **yonder**. It is used regionally, not generally.

> The dog is yonder, near the tree.

There is a subtle difference between **yonder** and **over**. Yonder can stand alone and mean "over there", that is, "at that place on the other side of the span of distance between here and there."

> The dog is yonder.

But we cannot say

> The dog is over. <sup>no</sup>

We have to say

> The dog is over there.

The word **over** requires something to complete its meaning, a location word or a location phrase.

Or **over** can mean "*crossing the space between two reference points".

> Go *over* to the dog near the tree and give it this shin bone.